# Login in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

Is there a way I can make the system compare the user input of ID and password with the ones in the database. So far it doesn't work because it still returns to login page eventhough i entered the correct ID and password.

This is the index.xhtml:

```
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">USERNAME  :</td>
                                <td align="left"><h:inputText id="staffID" value="#{loginCheck.staffID}" required="true" requiredMessage="*Please Fill In The Field" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td/><td colspan="2" align="left"><h:message for="staffID" class="error_message" style="font-size: 11px; color: red"/></td></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td align="right">PASSWORD  :</td>
                                <td align="left"><h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{loginCheck.password}" required="true" requiredMessage="*Please Fill In The Field" /></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr><td/><td colspan="2" align="left"><h:message for="password" class="error_message" style="font-size: 11px; color: red"/></td></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" align="center"><h:commandButton value="LOGIN" action="#{loginCheck.checkValidUser}"></h:commandButton></td>
                            </tr>
```

and this is the loginChecker:

```
    public void dbData(String staffID){
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc,Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/otawaDB","root","");
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            SQL = "SELECT * from staff where staffID like ('" + staffID + "')";
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
            dbStaffID = resultSet.getString(1).toString();
            dbPassword = resultSet.getString(2).toString();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Exception Occured In The Process: " + ex);
        }
    }
```